# Eclipse, CDT, add custom step in "clean" step

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have several shell scripts generating source files. Apart from final, result files, they also create few artifacts, like log files, temporary objects for easier debugging when something goes wrong and so on. I'd like to add custom step to the process run when I select "Project -> Clean..." that would delete all generated files. I'm using automatically generated Makefiles and would like to avoid writing my own. Not that I can't, I just that I'd rather spend my time doing more Real Work than Cumbersome Management.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to "clean" a file (*with a specific example for a map file*) that should work well.

To clean multiple files you could add multiple 'Builders' - one for each of your files. Or, create a script that cleans them all together.

**To manage the deletion of the Map file when using "Clean"**:

*Note: build each target (typically Debug and Release) to create the folders for the "Refresh" step below*

- Open the properties of the project
- Click on **Builders**
- Click the **New** button.
- Choose **Program**, and press the OK button.
- Replace the default name "New_Builder" with a meaningful name. For this example:

  > Delete Map File
- Enter the name of the program in the **Location:** edit box.

  > /bin/rm
- Enter the desired arguments to the command

  > ${project_loc}/${config_name:${project_name}}/${project_name}.map
- Click on the **Refresh** tab and select appropriate settings. For this example:

  - > Enable **Refresh resources upon completion**
  - > Un-check **Recursively include sub-folders**
  - > Select **Specific resources**
  - > Click the **Specify Resources...** button
  - > Expand the specific project and place a check mark next to "Debug" and "Release"
  - > Press the **Finish** button.
- Click on the **Build Options** tab and select appropriate settings. For this example:

  - > Un-check **Allocate Console (necessary for input)**
  - > Only check the option **During a "Clean"** in section **Run the builder:**
  - > Press the **OK** button.
- Press the **Apply and Close** button.

Answer (score 1):

@jędrzej-dudkiewicz

Wow! I spent about a workday to solve exactly the same issue, and now I read your post...
But I want to present more "accurate" fix of the problem: you need to add new rule with phony target, let's say `superclean`, to the (for example) `makefile.targets` file -- it will be included to main `makefile`; then you need to add `superclean` (separating it by space from other targets already listed there) to the appropriate field "Clean" at "Behaviour" page of the "C/++ Build" in the project properties dialogue. And voilà!

EDIT:

Unfortunately mentioned method may give some unwanted effects. The fact is that the `makefile` which is generated by the Eclipse CDT has lines like this:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif
```

and when you will try to clean your project `make` will try to include files listed in the `*_DEPS` variables. This is because `ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)` don't work because, in turn, `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` holds `superclean clean` value in our case. Though this variant may work yet if only you will not insert rule like this one

```
%.d: %.o
    ...
```

somewhere in your project's `makefile`. Because in this case `make` probably will try to generate the absent `.d` files being included.

So I think there is one more way to resolve this issue: simply append a list of the (automatically) generated files which you want to be deleted during cleaning of a project to one of a variables which are mentioned here:

```
# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) oc
    -@echo ' '
```

This is a quote from autogenerated `makefile`. You can do it something like this way:

```
ifneq ($(findstring clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
EXECUTABLES+=$(LIST_OF_THE_GENERATED_FILES)
endif
```

Comment: Nice! I never found it, although I've been looking around for a day, just like you. Well, I guess that someone else will come and tell us how to do it in even nicer way :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following solution: In properties, C/C++ Build, Builder Settings, Builder there is "Build command" box and "Use default build command" check box.

So it's pretty simply, though dirty - I've replace "make" with "customMake" - it intercepts invocation, checks for "clean" parameter and executes scripts that I've selected.

It's quite possible that there's a better solution but I had no luck finding it.

There is also another way. Create file makefile.targets in root directory of your project and create rule 'clean' repeating steps executed by makefile from Release/Debug/Whatever directory and add custom steps there. Example:

clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C_DEPS)$(ARCHIVES) libmpos.a
    echo PLACE CUSTOM STEPS HERE

Unfortunately make warns about rule override:

../makefile.targets:2: warning: overriding commands for target `clean'
makefile:52: warning: ignoring old commands for target`clean'

but it works and seems to be a better solution than previous one.